# What is difference between conservative caching and progressive caching in joomla 2.5?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0, joomla3.1

In Global Config in joomla have 2 caching is conservative and progressive, what is difference both ?

Comment: Here is nice article about the Global Config-caching in Joomla. click below link to see. http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-25/caching/global-module-caching

Comment: this says it better and faster - http://www.itoctopus.com/why-progressive-caching-in-joomla-should-be-avoided-in-most-cases but the above article backs up the answer with experimenting. If you have time read both, if you need a quick, good answer, read this one :)

Answer (score 33):

> **Conservative caching** is the standard type of caching. Here’s how it works:
>
> - A visitor visits a page on your website.
> - Joomla checks if there is a non-expired version of that page in its    cache directory.
> - If the cached page exists (and it’s not expired), then Joomla will    serve it to the visitor – otherwise, a cached version of the page is created, and that cached version will be served to the visitor, and to every other consequent visitor, as long as it’s (by “it” we mean the page) not expired.
>
> The above scenario is typical and is how most developers implement
>   caching.
>
> **Progressive caching** works the following way:
>
> - A visitor visits a page on your website.
> - Joomla checks if a cached version of that page exists for that visitor and it’s not yet expired.
> - If that cached page exists, then it’ll be served to the visitor,    otherwise, Joomla will create the cached page for that specific visitor and then will serve it to him.
> - If another visitor (who has never been on that page) visits that    page, then Joomla will not serve the cached page of the previous visitor, instead, it will create a cached version of that page
>     specifically for that user, and then serves it to him.
>
> As you can see, progressive caching only offers a performance
>   improvement if the same visitor visits the same page within the
>   lifetime of the cached version of the page. In most scenarios,
>   progressive caching results in a huge performance hit that is far
>   worse than disabling cache, simply because for nearly every visit,
>   Joomla has to process the request, create the cached version of the
>   page, and then serve the page to the visitor (instead of just
>   processing the request and serving the page in the scenario where
>   cache is disabled). Oh, and don’t forget about all the cache files
>   generated by Joomla – you can only imagine how many of these files you
>   will have in your cache folder if you have a high traffic news website
>   (that has many pages).
>
> Now you might wonder, under which circumstances is progressive caching
>   useful? Well, imagine that you have a video website (similar to
>   youtube). You want to show each visitor customized pages based on his
>   location and/or browser settings and/or plugins installed. So, for
>   every page that the visitors loads, you use this information to
>   generate a customized version of that page and you cache it. If the
>   visitor visits that same page again, then Joomla doesn’t need to redo
>   the work to generate the customized page.
>
> Of course, there are many scenarios under which progressive caching is
>   really useful, but in our opinion, progressive caching should only be
>   considered if the website receives many visitors and if those visitors
>   are mostly repeat visitors. Using it in other cases will cause a
>   significant hit on the website’s performance.

Extracted from [here](http://www.itoctopus.com/why-progressive-caching-in-joomla-should-be-avoided-in-most-cases).

Comment: I cant stress more on the "performance hit" progressive cache has! I have a busy website with a lot of returning users and thought progressive cache will be the choice. But it ended up choking my website. The server RAM usage spiked, CPU usage increased and the page started taking more an 1 minute just to load! Had a nightmare launch. As soon as I disabled the cache, the page loaded in 3 secs. Ever since, I never use the caching and only use memcache for session handlers!

Answer (score 11):

For **Unique cache per visitor**

- **Conservative cache** shows all visitors to your site the same exact cached content.
- **Progressive caching** however caches the content for each user uniquely.

From the [link](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-25/caching/global-module-caching) Provided by @Tornado's comment

Answer (score 1):

Progressive caching works just like conservative caching with a difference that buffers are updated progressively.

If you look at the render function in JApplicationCMS (where progressive caching is set), you will find that its not applicable to logged in users.
https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/cms/application/cms.php

```
if ($this->isSite() && $this->get('caching') && $this->get('caching', 2) == 2 && !JFactory::getUser()->get('id'))
    {
        $caching = true;
    }
```

Further if you dump the cache id's for the same page across browsers or ips you will get the same cache id's.

The typical work of progressive caching happens in JCache's getWorkarounds and setWorkarounds. However beware, the cbuffers can get unwieldy large at times causing issues.