# Same user visit, show other content?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, cookies, joomla

Is there a plugin/module for Joomla or WordPress, that can register if it the same user/computer that maybe visit a page on my site that is about Cameras that say.

And the next time he visit my webpage again, It shows another content in the same page.

So what im trying to say is, same visit user/computer, show other version of content/page?

Is there a plugin for that for any CMS framework?

Comment: Hello @Dennis ... This is not a good format or question for this website as it's not a programming issue you are facing, you are simply asking us to google this for you. Please reformat your question to a specific problem you are facing, any things you have tried, and so on.

Comment: @sulfureous - I get what you're saying, but for people who are new to this, a lot of times Googling yields no results - you don't always know how to phrase your question or describe what it is you're looking for in a way that returns results.

Comment: With 4 downvotes as you can see I'm not the only one considering this, the question is now on hold. I'm not trying to bash on anyone, I respect everyone for trying, but it's a matter of moderating the site so we have better quality questions and answers. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not a WordPress-specific plugin, Aware.js sounds like what you might be looking for: https://github.com/xoxco/awarejs

Using it does require a bit of programming knowledge, though, and I think you might be hard pressed to find something that does what you're looking for in plugin form at this time.

Comment: Thanks, thats might what im looking for :-)

Comment: Glad I could help, Dennis!

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about e-commerce and you want an out of box solution just use [virtuemart](http://virtuemart.net/) with Joomla. The featured page will show your products by a random order (default). You can also create modules with the option of random enable.

About [cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739297/what-is-difference-between-conservative-caching-and-progressive-caching-in-jooml) (but this doesn't affect the random options of virtuemart, only joomla direct content):

**Conservative Cache**

```
Shows all visitors to your site the same exact cached content.
```

**Progressive Caching**

```
However caches the content for each user uniquely.
```

Comment: I was not thinking e-commerce, but maybe i can use that in future, thanks :-)

Comment: @Dennis If you disable caching, you always have diferent content for diferent users. This is a joomla feature, independent of virtuemart.