# Joomla 500 error after enable cache

Tags: caching, joomla, http-status-code-500

I need your help guys..

I enabled conservative caching on my Joomla website due to very slow loading speed.

It reduced loading time from 5 to 2 seconds.
But I am getting 500 error on some K2 pages (for example: any link on this page: http://elody.cz/clanky get 500 error because it is links to K2 modules)

I enabled Joomla cache plugin, I cleared all cache on Joomla website.
Joomla updated, k2 updated

**UPDATE:**
When I delete cache and before visiting any other page I visit K2, the current article what I visited works. But any other does not work...

Any suggestions please?
Filip

Answer (score 0):

Just from my experience:

- Is htaccess.txt renamed to .htaccess?
- Is the plugin "browser caching" enabled?
- is Gzip turned on?
- Take a look between the right caching settings for you? [What is difference between conservative caching and progressive caching in joomla 2.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739297/what-is-difference-between-conservative-caching-and-progressive-caching-in-jooml)
- Maybe there is a setting in K2 about caching?

Comment: By browser caching you mean Joomla - Cache plugin?

Yes, everything should be okay. After allowing error reporting I get this error:

 Call to undefined function hikashop_get() in /data/web/virtuals/93721/virtual/www/domains/elody.cz/tmp/htmldZc4uj on line 5

Comment: I asume you are using hikashop? Maybe contact the developers about this, as i have no experience with HikaShop :/